# If you wanted to privately receive bitcoin from someone, how would you do that?

Tags: security, privacy, wallet-security

I do not like to be tracked when receiving or sending bitcoins.

How do you make a secure wallet?

If you wanted to privately get bitcoin from someone, how do you get it?

How do you get the address to the person who is going to give you the bitcoin?

Answer (score 1):

I believe "anonymously" is a better fit than "secretly". Since every transaction is public and you can't hide the transfer of coins. What you can hide is the identity of the parties involved.

As for creating a wallet, you can run your own node, possibly having a hardware wallet (not strictly necessary but it helps).

As for getting the coins, I'd say you need to avoid centralized exchanges, debit card gateway payments, and anything that requires KYC. You also probably want to meet in person and pay cash. [LocalBitcoin](https://localbitcoins.com/) has been an option for years, just be careful and do your own research.

As for the address, you want to avoid messaging apps, unencrypted (or even weak encryption) protocols, and possibly show/share the address in person.

Additionally, there are services that "mix" your coins to make them harder to know their precedence, in a process very similar to money laundry in the conventional money world. Two famous options are [Wasabi](https://wasabiwallet.io/) and [Samourai](https://samouraiwallet.com/) wallets.

Comment: Coinjoins are not money laundering. Comparing apples and oranges. Its a transaction in which outputs look similar. You can create transactions with your own wallet addresses that look like coinjoin. Also Samourai has lot of issues, won't suggest their wallet or coinjoin implementation. Joinmarket and Wasabi are good enough options for privacy.

Comment: Personal opinion: Never meet anyone in person to buy/sell bitcoin. And Localbitcoin is not a good option anymore. Things have changed and they have lot of issues. Bisq and HodlHodl are better.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you make a secure wallet?

Security depends on lot of things including user and not just the wallets. Most of the open source Bitcoin wallets with active development are secure.

> If you wanted to secretly get bitcoin from someone, how do you get it?

Share your address privately and ask them to send bitcoin. Follow best practices:

[image: best-practices]

> How do you get the address to the person who is going to give you the bitcoin?

There are lot of ways to communicate privately. Some people prefer PGP if using email, for instant messaging XMPP is good enough and lot of other options however this is offtopic.